# Pytesseract identifies a repeated question mark as different characters

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I cropped a screenshot to start with a simple example. This is the picture I want to convert to string:

[image]

I did use pytesseract and opencv to process the picture:

[image]

The string I get is as follows:

> Stage 4-2: 22?
> ♀

I am new to OCR and after reading documentation and playing around with different types of preprocessing, this is the best result I get. My questions:

- Why is the last question mark recognized but the two before that are not?
- Is the repition of special characters not expected?
- Why is there a "♀" ?

Thank you for your help.

Code:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
image = cv2.imread('stage.png')

grey = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(grey, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cv2.imwrite("test.png", thresh)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 7')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

After further playing around, resizing the picture and stretching it horizontally by a factor of 1.5 got me the right solution.